# invalid field found for struct models.User's field Identities: define a valid foreign key for relations or implement the Valuer/Scanner interface

Tags: go, go-gorm

Always got an error when I add the relationship to the User in GitUser struct.

```
type GitUser struct {
  ID               uint `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey"`
  ExternalID       string
  JobID            uint
  UserID          uint

  User User `gorm:"foreignKey:UserID;references:ID"`
  Job  Job  `gorm:"foreignKey:JobID;references:ID"`
}

type User struct {
  ID             uint `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey"`
  ExternalId     *string
  Username       string
  Email          string
  Name           string
  HashedPassword *string
  AvatarUrl      *string
  IsAdmin        bool
  LastSignInAt   *time.Time
  CreatedAt time.Time
  UpdatedAt      time.Time
  IsArchived     bool

  GitUser     []GitUser
}
```

I'm trying to make a mutual relationship between User and GitUser

Comment: The error is on field `Identities`. Please include its schema

Comment: Thks  I find my mistake. I didn't define the `UserID` in `UserIndetity` model